# Как менять стили блока при достижении определенной части страницы?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, веб-программирование

У меня есть header (самый вверх страницы):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но есть одна проблема - при достижении определенной части страницы текста кнопок header'а не видно! Например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е кнопки как бы есть, но цвет фона белый и цвет кнопок header'а также белый, из за чего их не видно. Единственное что приходит в голову - менять стили при достижения определенной части страницы, чтобы при достижении блока с белым фоном, текст header'a менялся на черный. Как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите решение на чистом css, то лучше просто выделить текст на кнопках тенью. Я бы сделал именно так.

```
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
```

Но есть вариант и по вашему. Вам надо разместить клон headerа на белую область с `position: sticky`. Светлый блок должен быть `overflow: hidden`. Клон хедера надо поднять на свою высоту выше верхней границы белого блока, в котором и находится сам клон шапки, чтобы его не было видно, пока белая область не достигла верха экрана.